# mod_rewrite folder to query string?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to mod_rewrite the below:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/$variable   to    http://www.domain.com/file.php?$variable
```

I have tried this which doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/\.]+)/?$ folder/file.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Is it off by a lot?

Answer (score 2):

works, hadn't turned `mod_rewrite` on!